# cuRAND expected an expression

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm learning C++ for a project, and for my project I need to generate a random number on the GPU.
For this, I decided to use `cuRAND`.
However, I'm running into a small issue on this line:

```
random << <1, 1 >> >(time(NULL), gpu_x);
```

I got the error `expected an expression` on that line.

using this code, which I got from [here](http://cs.umw.edu/~finlayson/class/fall16/cpsc425/notes/cuda-random.html):

```
__global__ void random(unsigned int seed, int* result) {
    /* CUDA's random number library uses curandState_t to keep track of the seed value
    we will store a random state for every thread  */
    curandState_t state;

    /* we have to initialize the state */
    curand_init(seed, /* the seed controls the sequence of random values that are produced */
        0, /* the sequence number is only important with multiple cores */
        0, /* the offset is how much extra we advance in the sequence for each call, can be 0 */
        &state);

    /* curand works like rand - except that it takes a state as a parameter */
    *result = curand(&state) % MAX;
}

void Miner::GoMine() {
    int* gpu_x;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&gpu_x, sizeof(int));

    /* invoke the GPU to initialize all of the random states */
    random << <1, 1 >> >(time(NULL), gpu_x);

    /* copy the random number back */
    int x;
    cudaMemcpy(&x, gpu_x, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printf("Random number = %d.\n", x);

    /* free the memory we allocated */
    cudaFree(gpu_x);
}
```

As I am new to C++, I couldn't figure out what is going on.
I hope somebody here was able to help me?

Cheers

Comment: This isn't just C++ though, there is some CUDA specific syntax in there as far as I can tell. Are you invoking the proper compilation steps for that?

Comment: You can't have spaces in the CUDA code here: `random << <1, 1 >> >` should be `random <<<1, 1 >>>`, the triple angled brackets are parsed by the CUDA pre-processor

Comment: Make sure you have set up a CUDA project in visual studio, and make sure the code you are showing is in a file that ends in `.cu`  Also, you may be confusing an intellisense error for an actual build issue.  If this is an intellisense error you are referring to, you should ignore that.  The only errors that matter are the ones the compiler generates.

Comment: It's a build error (it prevents me from building the program).
Is there a way to make it work in C++?

Comment: I've deleted my answer as it was based on an assumption which is incorrect. Did you install the CUDA SDK and did you create a CUDA project or just a plain C++ project and then just added the code? You need to include under Build Dependencies->Build Customizations a reference to the CUDA X.X (.targets, .props), this will recognise what to do with `.cu` files

Comment: @RobertCrovella yep, you're correct, I assumed that triple angle brackets would be an issue but it's fine, just tested it on my own project and there were no issues using VS 2015

Comment: No, you can't use CUDA runtime API syntax (e.g. `__global__` or the triple angle brackets) in an ordinary C++ project in VS.  You must use a properly set-up CUDA project, and you should have the file extension be `.cu` instead of `.cpp` so that the `nvcc` compiler gets invoked for that file.

Comment: I started it as a plain C++ project and then slapped in the code.
I checked `CUDA9.0` in the `Build Customizations`, renamed the file to `miner.cu` (from `miner.cpp`) but still nothing.

@RobertCrovella so I should make a clean project as CUDA project then just add the current code as-is?

Comment: When starting with a non-CUDA project with existing sources files, you should be able to convert it to a CUDA-aware project by selecting the build customizations.  And you do need a file that ends in `.cu`.  But I think if you simply rename a `.cpp` file to `.cu` it may not pick up the build customizations. I think it will be easier, after you select the build customizations, to add a new CUDA source file to the project.  This is fairly easy to spot, because in the compile output you should see `nvcc` invoked for the .cu file instead of `cl.exe`.

Comment: Hmmm okay, I get what you say.
So making a CUDA source file for running the `cuRAND` stuff should be a way to go?

Comment: I think if you're new to all this the best thing is just to start over with a new CUDA project.  Or take one of the CUDA samples and drop your code in there. What you're struggling with here is VS project configuration.

Comment: I will post an answer to my issue in a moment :D (yes, I managed to figure it out after a while)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the issue by placing the CUDA related code in `cuRAND.cu` (`Add -> New Item -> CUDA 9.0 -> Code -> CUDA C/C++ File`).

I renamed the function `void Miner::GoMine()` to `int cuRND()`
I added some extra code so my entire `cuRAND.cu` file now looks like this:

```
// For the RNG using CUDA
#include <curand.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include "sha256.h"

#ifndef __Kernel_CU__  
#define __Kernel_CU__  

#define MAX 100

__global__ void random(unsigned int seed, int* result) {
    /* CUDA's random number library uses curandState_t to keep track of the seed value
we will store a random state for every thread  */
curandState_t state;

    /* we have to initialize the state */
    curand_init(seed, /* the seed controls the sequence of random values that are produced */
    0, /* the sequence number is only important with multiple cores */
    0, /* the offset is how much extra we advance in the sequence for each call, can be 0 */
    &state);

    /* curand works like rand - except that it takes a state as a parameter */
    *result = curand(&state) % MAX;
}


extern "C"

int cuRND() {
    int* gpu_x;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&gpu_x, sizeof(int));

    /* invoke the GPU to initialize all of the random states */
    random <<< 1, 1 >> >(time(NULL), gpu_x);

    /* copy the random number back */
    int x;
    cudaMemcpy(&x, gpu_x, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    /* free the memory we allocated */
    cudaFree(gpu_x);

        return floor(99999999 * x);
}
#endif
```

I then proceeded to add this code to my `miner.cpp` (which is the file I need it in):

```
extern "C"   
int cuRND();
```

I can now make a call to `cuRND()` from my `miner.cpp`.
Hit start, and I was off to the races!
Thanks for the help, I hope this answer can help somebody later down the road!